# I Separated the Bird into Loose Parts, how Do I Animate Those Loose Parts Independently, without everything else being animated?

Tags: animation

The bird in the picture is a whole bunch of loose parts combined by Ctrl J. I separated it in edit mode. Now, whenever I try to animate the wings of the bird, the whole body is animated to, only when I animate the wings.

I am very new to blender.

[image]

Comment: maybe work some tutorials about rigging

Comment: If the birds' wings are separate mesh from their respective bodies, you can animate the wings without problems.  Are they indeed sparated?  When you click on a wing, does the entire bird become outlined/highlited?

Comment: No, only the wing I selected becomes highlighted. I tried to solve this by creating an armature, but I would still like to animate them as meshes and not armatures.

Comment: Could it be that the wings have modifiers acting on them, or perhaps parented in reverse - i.e. wing = parent of the main body?  If none of these can you upload your Blend file or the birds part of it?  From what you describe, the animation should be straight forward.

Comment: added to the above - If you're using bones/armatures on the wings it will be the way you've got them rigged and @Moonboot's suggestion would be the way to go.